# spark (python) dataframe - iterate over rows and columns in a block

Tags: python, loops, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've searched quite a bit and can't quite find a question similar to the problem I am trying to solve here:
I have a spark dataframe in python, and I need to loop over rows and certain columns in a block to determine if there are non-null values.

The data looks like this (putting it simplistically):
[image]

As you can see, I have sorted the data by the ID column. Each ID has potentially multiple rows with different values in the property1-property5 columns.
I need to loop over these to be able to check for each unique ID value, if there are any of the property columns (1 to 5) that are not null. I don't care what the values are fortunately - only whether they are null or not.
Hence I need the output to be something like this:

[image]

Here we see ID 101, 102 and 108 has some property values that are non-null. However ID 109 only has nulls.

I am not very skilled with Python - I know that I need some soft of a window function (window.partition) and then loop over the columns (for x : x in df.columns). I'd appreciate the help - as I mentioned, I've not been able to find another question that is quite similar to what I am trying to do.

My actual dataset had 167 columns (not all of which I need to consider) and a few million rows. I can easily drop the columns that I don't need to consider, so that I don't need to make a list of the ones that don't need to pass through the loop.

Comment: i'm thinking a `when().otherwise()` would work fine here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need loops (*well, for most cases in spark, this holds true*). A `when().otherwise()` can be used here.

Suppose, you have the input as following

```
data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls). \
    toDF(['id', 'prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3', 'prop4'])

# +---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
# | id|prop1|prop2|prop3|prop4|
# +---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
# |101| null| null| null| null|
# |101|    1| null| true|    0|
# |101|    0|    0| null|   10|
# |102|    1| null| true|    0|
# |102| null|    1| null| null|
# |109| null| null| null| null|
# |109| null| null| null| null|
# +---+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

You first check if any of the "prop" containing columns are non-null at a row level. I've used `reduce()` to avoid writing multiple columns.

```
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('has_prop',
               reduce(lambda x, y: x|y, [func.col(k).isNotNull() for k in data_sdf.columns if 'prop' in k])
               ). \
    show()

# +---+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------+
# | id|prop1|prop2|prop3|prop4|has_prop|
# +---+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------+
# |101| null| null| null| null|   false|
# |101|    1| null| true|    0|    true|
# |101|    0|    0| null|   10|    true|
# |102|    1| null| true|    0|    true|
# |102| null|    1| null| null|    true|
# |109| null| null| null| null|   false|
# |109| null| null| null| null|   false|
# +---+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------+

# The `reduce` generates the following logic
# Column<'((((prop1 IS NOT NULL) OR (prop2 IS NOT NULL)) OR (prop3 IS NOT NULL)) OR (prop4 IS NOT NULL))'>
```

The max of `has_prop` column at an `id` level would result in the required output. (`True > False`)

```
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('has_prop',
               reduce(lambda x, y: x|y, [func.col(k).isNotNull() for k in data_sdf.columns if 'prop' in k])
               ). \
    groupBy('id'). \
    agg(func.max('has_prop').alias('has_prop')). \
    show()

# +---+--------+
# | id|has_prop|
# +---+--------+
# |101|    true|
# |102|    true|
# |109|   false|
# +---+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you - I dont understand the reduce and the lambda function, but it works. :)

Comment: @GenDemo - [`lambda` functions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) are anonymous functions, which in this case is nothing but an OR operator. The [`reduce` function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reduce-in-python/) applies a function recursively to a collection of values - in this case, it is applying the OR operator to the list of columns.

Comment: Thank you, that helps.
How does it know what x and y is? because it is not referenced in the loop.

Comment: @GenDemo - there is no loop involved in the lambda. x and y are elements of the list of columns.

Comment: magic!  - thnx @samkart, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in 2 steps

1. Firstly using the inherent property for `max` & `min` to
   determine if all the rows are null.
2. Build a consolidated map to mark if all rows are nulls not null

A similar approach & question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73077309/how-i-discard-columns-with-all-values-null-in-apache-spark/73077652#73077652)

#### Data Preparation

```
s = StringIO("""
ID,Company,property1,property2,property3,property4,property5
101,A,,,,,
102,Z,'1','0','0','TRUE',
103,M,'0','0','0','FALSE','FALSE'
104,C,'1','1','0','TRUE','FALSE'
105,F,'0','1',,'TRUE',
""")

df = pd.read_csv(s,delimiter=',').fillna('None') #.reset_index()

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)

sparkDF = reduce(
    lambda df2, x: df2.withColumn(x, F.when(F.col(x) == 'None',F.lit(None)).otherwise(F.col(x))),
    [i for i in sparkDF.columns],
    sparkDF,
)

sparkDF.show()

+---+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| ID|Company|property1|property2|property3|property4|property5|
+---+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|101|      A|     null|     null|     null|     null|     null|
|102|      Z|      '1'|      '0'|      '0'|   'TRUE'|     null|
|103|      M|      '0'|      '0'|      '0'|  'FALSE'|  'FALSE'|
|104|      C|      '1'|      '1'|      '0'|   'TRUE'|  'FALSE'|
|105|      F|      '0'|      '1'|     null|   'TRUE'|     null|
+---+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

#### Null Row Identification & Marking

```
ID_null_map = sparkDF.groupBy('Id').agg(*[(
                 (
                    F.min(F.col(c)).isNull() 
                  & F.max(F.col(c)).isNull()
                 )
                | ( F.min(F.col(c)) != F.max(F.col(c)) )
                ).alias(c)
                 for c in sparkDF.columns if 'property' in c
                ]
              ).withColumn('combined_flag',F.array([c for c in ID_null_map.columns if 'property' in c]))\
               .withColumn('nulls_free',F.forall('combined_flag', lambda x: x == False))\

ID_null_map.show(truncate=False)

+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------+----------+
|Id |property1|property2|property3|property4|property5|combined_flag                      |nulls_free|
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------+----------+
|103|false    |false    |false    |false    |false    |[false, false, false, false, false]|true      |
|104|false    |false    |false    |false    |false    |[false, false, false, false, false]|true      |
|105|false    |false    |true     |false    |true     |[false, false, true, false, true]  |false     |
|101|true     |true     |true     |true     |true     |[true, true, true, true, true]     |false     |
|102|false    |false    |false    |false    |true     |[false, false, false, false, true] |false     |
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------+----------+
```

With the above dataset , you can join it further on `Id` to get the desired rows